# Adding run number when appending data frame to CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am running a simulation in python, writing results to Pandas DataFrame and appending data to a CSV file. The code will be run multiple times with possible variation of parameters. Is there a smart way to record run number of the simulation to the CSV file for future data analysis?

```
    import pandas as pd
    import random

    # Create a data frame with random values of random length, append
    # to a data frame and write to file.

    df = dp.DataFrame()

    for i in range(3):
       length = random.randint(3,20)
       aa = [random.randint(0,25) for i in range(length)]
       aa = [random.randint(0,25) for i in range(length)]
       run_n = [i * length]

       aabb = list(zip(aa, bb, run_n)
       aabb_df = pd.DataFrame(data=aabb, columns=['aa', 'bb', 'run_N'])
       df = df.append(aabb_df)

    with open(myfile, 'a') as csvfile:
       df.to_csv(csvfile, index=False, header=False)
```

Recording the number of the run from the for-loop is straight forward, however I suspect incorrect. Is it possible to check the number of the run and continue counting from there without reading the whole file in.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could always make the run number an integer drawn from a uniform random distribution such that it's highly unlikely two of the same values will ever be drawn:

```
run_n = np.random.randint(1e9)
```

Or, you can increment each run number so that there is a guarantee no two runs will have the same `run_n` using a `counter` strategy.